# Make a string bold that is displayed in both a RadGrid txtNote and a label

Tags: c#

I have a RadGrid that shows a txtNote as text in its note column.  I also have a label called lblShowAllSessionNotes.  When A session note is added or appended to an existing note, a type of ID stamp preceeds the actual txt message, like so:

**NoteTYPE - CommunicationType - ContactType** 
**Electronically signed by**:  someone's Name  6/12/2016 12:00:00
This is the note text.  It  is text.

If I put **...** in the string variable in code behind, then in the radGrid it appears as:  **Electronically signed by**: someone's name; instead of **Electronically signed by**: someone's name....   In the label it appears bold as expected.

I have a method:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Creates and shows all session notes in a text format.
    /// </summary>
    protected void ShowAllSessionNotes()
    {
        var allNotes = new StringBuilder();
        string splitStr = "";
        string[] newStr = null;

        foreach (var noteItem in SessionNotes())
            {
                allNotes.Append("<b>" + noteItem.DmSessionNoteType + " - </b>");
                allNotes.Append("<b>" + noteItem.DmCommunicationType + " - </b>");
                allNotes.Append("<b>" + noteItem.DmContactType + " - </b>");
                allNotes.Append(noteItem.AddDateTime + " (CST)");

                if (ShowDuration)
                {
                    allNotes.AppendFormat(" - <b>Duration:</b> {0} - <b>Electronically signed by: </b> {1}",
                    FormatDuration(noteItem.Duration), noteItem.CCName);
                }
                if (noteItem.Note.Contains('|'))
                {
                    splitStr = noteItem.Note;
                    newStr = splitStr.Split('|');
                    noteItem.Note = String.Join("<br/>", newStr);
                }

            if (noteItem.Note.Contains(':') && noteItem.Note.StartsWith("Electronically"))
            {
                splitStr = noteItem.Note;
                string bldStr = splitStr.Split(':')[0];
            }

                allNotes.Append("<br />");
                allNotes.Append(noteItem.Note);
                allNotes.Append("<br /><br />");
            }


            lblShowAllSessionNotes.Text = allNotes.ToString();
            lblShowAllSessionNotes.Visible = true;
        }
```

and another....

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Helper function that populates a session note entity.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The GridEditableItem to pull data from.</param>
    /// <param name="sessionNote">Existing PatientSessionNote entity.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns a populated PatientSessionNote entity.</returns>
    private PatientSessionNote PopulatePatientSessionNote(GridEditableItem item, ref List<string> errors)
    {
        var id = item.ItemIndex != -1 ? Convert.ToInt32(item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[item.ItemIndex]["ID"]) : 0;
        var rcb = item.FindControl("radCmbNoteType") as RadComboBox;
        var rcbCC = item.FindControl("radCmbCommunicationType") as RadComboBox;
        var rcbC = item.FindControl("radCmbContactType") as RadComboBox;
        var rtb = item.FindControl("rtbNote") as RadTextBox;
        string userSign = "Electronically signed by: ";             
        var appendDate = DateTime.Now;
        var appendUser = User.Identity.Name;
        var appendName = new MasterBLL().getUserName(appendUser);   
        var origSessNote = item.FindControl("HideOriginalSessionNote") as HiddenField;   
        string sessionNoteSent = "";



        if (origSessNote.Value == "".Trim() || origSessNote == null)
        {
            sessionNoteSent = rtb.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            sessionNoteSent = origSessNote.Value + " | " + Environment.NewLine + userSign + appendName + " " + appendDate.ToString() + " | " + Environment.NewLine + rtb.Text;
        }

        var sessionNote = new PatientSessionNote
    {
            Id = id,
            PatientId = _patientId,
            DeleteReason = string.Empty,
            IsDeleted = false,
            LastUpdateDateTime = DateTime.Now,
            LastUpdateUserName = CurrentUserId,
            CommunicationTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(rcbCC.SelectedValue),
            ContactTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(rcbC.SelectedValue),
            SessionNoteTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(rcb.SelectedValue),
            Note = Server.HtmlDecode(sessionNoteSent)                
        };            

        if (id == 0)
        {
            sessionNote.AddDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            sessionNote.AddUserName = CurrentUserId;
        }


        if (ShowDuration)
        {
            var rdpSessionDate = item.FindControl("rdpSessionDate") as RadDatePicker;
            var txtSessionStartTime = item.FindControl("txtSessionStartTime") as TextBox;
            var txtSessionEndTime = item.FindControl("txtSessionEndTime") as TextBox;

            //Set any existing values to NULL (for UPDATEs) so that validation doesn't allow incorrect inputs because of pre-existing old values
            //This values will be redefined thru the standard INSERT practices
            sessionNote.SessionStart = null;
            sessionNote.SessionEnd = null;
            sessionNote.Duration = 0;

            if (rdpSessionDate != null && txtSessionStartTime != null && txtSessionEndTime != null)
            {
                var regexDate = Regex.Match(rdpSessionDate.DbSelectedDate.ToString(), @"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}",
                    RegexOptions.Singleline);
                if (regexDate.Success)
                {
                    var startTime = Regex.Match(txtSessionStartTime.Text,
                        @"(?i)(?<Hours>\d{1,2}):(?<Minutes>\d{2})(?<Meridian>am|pm)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
                    var endTime = Regex.Match(txtSessionEndTime.Text,
                        @"(?i)(?<Hours>\d{1,2}):(?<Minutes>\d{2})(?<Meridian>am|pm)", RegexOptions.Singleline);

                    if (startTime.Success && endTime.Success)
                    {
                        //SessionStart & SessionEnd Dates
                        DateTime varDate;
                        if (DateTime.TryParse(rdpSessionDate.DbSelectedDate.ToString(), out varDate))
                        {
                            var startHours = int.Parse(startTime.Groups["Hours"].Value)%12;
                            var endHours = int.Parse(endTime.Groups["Hours"].Value)%12;

                            var startMinutes = int.Parse(startTime.Groups["Minutes"].Value);
                            var endMinutes = int.Parse(endTime.Groups["Minutes"].Value);

                            var isStartAM = Regex.IsMatch(startTime.Groups["Meridian"].Value.ToLower(), "am");
                            var isEndAM = Regex.IsMatch(endTime.Groups["Meridian"].Value.ToLower(), "am");

                            if (varDate != DateTime.MinValue)
                            {
                                var startDate = new DateTime(varDate.Year, varDate.Month, varDate.Day,
                                    ((isStartAM) ? startHours : (startHours + 12)), startMinutes, 0);
                                var endDate = new DateTime(varDate.Year, varDate.Month, varDate.Day,
                                    ((isEndAM) ? endHours : (endHours + 12)), endMinutes, 0);
                                var span = endDate.Subtract(startDate);

                                sessionNote.SessionStart = startDate;

                                if (span.TotalMinutes > 0)
                                    //Only log if the amount of minutes is a positive number (integer)
                                {
                                    sessionNote.SessionEnd = endDate;
                                    sessionNote.Duration = (int) span.TotalMinutes;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    errors.Add(@"The start time is greater than the end time");
                                    errors.Add(@"Date chosen: " + rdpSessionDate.DbSelectedDate);
                                    errors.Add(@"Start date time: " + startDate);
                                    errors.Add(@"End date time: " + endDate);
                                    errors.Add(@"Total minutes: " + span.TotalMinutes);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                errors.Add(@"Invalid date format: " + rdpSessionDate.DbSelectedDate);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            errors.Add(@"Invalid date format: " + rdpSessionDate.DbSelectedDate);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!startTime.Success)
                        {
                            errors.Add(@"Invalid start time format: " + txtSessionStartTime.Text);
                        }
                        if (!endTime.Success)
                        {
                            errors.Add(@"Invalid end time format: " + txtSessionEndTime.Text);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    errors.Add(@"Invalid date format: " + rdpSessionDate.DbSelectedDate);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (rdpSessionDate == null)
                {
                    errors.Add(@"RadDatePicker ControlID ""rdpSessionDate"" could not be found");
                }
                if (txtSessionStartTime == null)
                {
                    errors.Add(@"TextBox ControlID ""txtSessionStartTime"" could not be found");
                }
                if (txtSessionEndTime == null)
                {
                    errors.Add(@"TextBox ControlID ""txtSessionEndTime"" could not be found");
                }                   
            }
        }

        if (errors.Count > 0)
        {
            errors.Add("Server date: " + DateTime.Today);
        }

        return sessionNote;
    }
```

If I put the bold tag < b > in the second method PopulatePatientSessionNote(...)  on string userSign then it works for the label but not for the grid.   I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok because of time constraints I've done this:  It's messy but it works.

I first added a property:

public string UserSign { get; set; }

In The PopulatePatientSessionNote(...) method I added this:

UserSign = "**" + userSign + "**";

sessionNoteSent = origSessNote.Value + " | " + Environment.NewLine + **"`"** + appendName + " " + appendDate.ToString() + " | " + Environment.NewLine + rtb.Text;

Then in the ShowAllSessionNotes (...) method I added:

splitStr = noteItem.Note;
                        newStr = splitStr.Split('`');
                        noteItem.Note = String.Join(UserSign, newStr);

It's messy but it works.  Does anyone one have a better idea?  Thx a bunch!!!